# How to navigate nodes using .firstChild

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say we have something like this:

```
<table class="abc">
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I wan't to display this value: Why this isn't correct:

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0].firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

and that is:

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

?

Comment: i would suggest you use document.querySelectorAll instead

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
This one works:
        `alert(document.querySelectorAll("table.abc>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(1)")[0].innerHTML);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your not working alert is due to the linebreaks and spaces between tags: if you try to alert

```
document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0].firstChild
```

with the code you provided, you would obtain a *textNode*, instead of a *DOMelement* as you're expecting. If you remove those spaces

```
<table class="abc"><tr><td>123</td></tr></table>
```

your alert may works, but you need to access `.firstChild` one more time, because the browser would insert a *table section element* (the `tbody`) into the `DOM` tree automatically for you.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0]
   .firstChild    /* tableSection DOM element */
   .firstChild    /* tableRow DOM element */
   .firstChild    /* tableCell DOM element */
   .firstChild    /* textNode */
   .nodeValue     /* 123 */
```

See this codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IAeJl

---

in the second example the problem doesn't exist, simply because you're accessing to the table row and table cell, whether they are *firstChild* nodes of their ancestors nodes or not

in any case, on modern browsers, you could access to that element simply by `document.querySelector('.abc td')`;